# QProcess - is it even possible to get exit status != 0 or `waitForFinished()` return False in a real scenario

Tags: qt

I spend several hours dealing with a quite simplistic problem - determining whether a child process (using `QProcess`) has crashed or exited normally. The big confusion was coming from the fact that `QProcess.waitForFinished` basically creates **three** values that one has to observe:

- The `return` value of the method itself - according to the documentation this value is `True` if the process has finished. Otherwise (in case of timeout, some error or if the process has already finished) it is `False`
- `ExitCode` - this is the exit code from the external process
- `ExitStatus` - this is the exit status of `QProcess`

I find the documentation quite confusing (for me that is). My task was to start a child process from a separate thread and then monitor it by using `QProcess.waitForStarted()`, `QProcess.waitForFinished()` etc. and report back to the UI.

At first I thought that catching the `return` value of `QProcess.waitForFinished()` would be enough. It sure was for `QProcess.waitForStarted()` where it worked like a charm - in case I was able to start the process I got `True`, otherwise - `False`. It is not that simple if you want to detect the crash in the external process though. At least in my `QProcess.waitForFinished()` returns `True` all the time. Not only that but the `ExitStatus` is also 0 all the time. This required some investigation.

If I do the following for example (I'm using PyQt4 here):

```
# Check if the process has finished properly
if self.ext_process.waitForFinished():
  # Emit a signal with some predefined exit status to the UI indicating success
  self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_OK_FINISHED)
else:
  # Emit a signal with some predefined exit status to the UI indicating failure
  self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_ERROR_FAIL_QUIT)
```

I'm **always** getting into the `if`'s body and never visit the `else`'s no matter if the process has crashed (I ran a Python script first with a division by zero to cause a crash and then tried `sys.exit(1)`). Now I guess that the `return` value of this method is NOT related to the external process at all but to the `QProcess` instance that is hooked to it (as the documentation points out). Okay, fair enough. Let's continue...

The next step was to check what the `ExitStatus` is for. It turns out that it is also something bound to the `QProcess` instance and not to the external process itself. So checking these two so far gives me the state of the `QProcess` instance and not the external process

Finally I got it working by doing the following check:

```
# Check if the process has finished properly (both the QProcess instance and the external process itself by checking its exit code)
if self.ext_process.waitForFinished() and not self.ext_process.exitCode():
  # Emit a signal with some predefined exit status to the UI indicating success
  self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_OK_FINISHED)
else:
  # Emit a signal with some predefined exit status to the UI indicating failure
  self.emit(self.signalFinishedExtProc, self.EXT_PROC_STATUS_ERROR_FAIL_QUIT)
```

I wonder in what **real** scenario might `QProcess.waitForFinished()` return `False` or the `ExitStatus` become 1? Especially the part where the `QProcess` instance doesn't finish properly. I'm excluding the timeout case because I can imagine why this could be useful - for example if we know that the childprocess requires let's say 10ms to finish but instead all of a sudden it needs 20ms to do that.

Comment: waitForFinished() return false not when the process fails, but if it doesn’t terminate in the time specified (optional argument for waitForFinished()). So  for a process crashing in time it will still return true. exitStatus should reflect the crash (i.e. equal QProcess.CrashExit) in case waitForFinished() return true and the process crashed. Accordingly for exitCode().

Comment: The documentation says otherwise about `waitForFinished()`: Returns true if the process finished; otherwise returns false (if the operation timed out, if an error occurred, or if this QProcess is already finished). I'm wondering mostly how the second can happen. It is not related to the external process' state but to the `QProcess`'s instance.

Comment: I’d double-check. "If an error occurred” might mean something went wrong with the QProcess<->actual process communication. I don’t think it refers to the process crashing or returning and exit code != 0 (which is totally valid from the QProcess perspective).

Comment: Yes, it refers to  the instance of `QProcess` itself and not the external process as I have discovered during my struggle with `waitForFinished()`. :D I'd like a solid scenario where `False` is returned. It is important for me since the external processes that I'm starting with my UI application are critical (unlike the UI iteself) and ensure that the system is working properly.